# Etiqueta de servidor incorrecta al dar clic en el menú

Tags: c#, asp.net

Cordial saludo. Estamos desarrollando un aplicativo para control de llantas. En este aplicativo nos encontramos en la capa de presentación y se nos esta presentando el siguiente error: etiqueta de servidor incorrecta o the server tag is not well formed. Lo que hemos podido leer en internet con respecto a este error, esta relacionado con el uso de comillas dobles (" ") donde se deben usar comillas simples (' ') y otro de los errores no cerrar una etiqueta relacionada con el servidor. Revisando ambas opciones, encuentro que nuestro código cumple con ambas, pero a pesar de ello, no conseguimos encontrar la causas del error. Procedemos a compartirles el código.

```
    <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="AFLlantasSalidasRegistro.ascx.cs" Inherits="DesktopModules_AF_AFLlantasSalidasRegistro" %>

<%--Este código es necesario para informar acciones o errores utlizando los modulos desarrollados por Pablo Herrera.--%>
<%@ Register Src="~/DesktopModules/AF/Comunes/MensajesControl.ascx" TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="MensajesControl" %>
<uc1:MensajesControl runat="server" ID="MensajesControl" />

<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>

        <%--Contruyo el encabezado de la tabla--%>
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <th>IdLlanta</th>
                <th>UbicacionLlanta</th>
                <th>ProfundidadLlanta</th>
                <th>OperacionLlanta</th>
                <th>EstadoLlanta</th>
                <th>HorometroEquipo</th>
                <th>OdometroEquipo</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TBIdLlanta" TextMode="SingleLine" />
                    <%--2024-02-20: Validacion que busca que obligatoriamente se ingresen datos--%>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ErrorMessage="Requerido" ControlToValidate="TBIdLlanta" runat="server"
                        Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="Edicion" ForeColor="Red" />
                    <%--2024-02-20: Validacion que busca identificar si el codigo esta en el inventario--%>
                    <asp:CustomValidator ErrorMessage="No Invetario" ControlToValidate="TBIdLlanta" 
                        runat="server" ID="CVInvetarioId" OnServerValidate="CVInvetarioId_ServerValidate" 
                        Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="Edicion" ForeColor="Red" />
                    <%--2024-02-20: Validacion para identificar si la llanta esta activa en otro vehiculo--%>
                    <asp:CustomValidator ErrorMessage="Rodando" ControlToValidate="TBIdLlanta"
                        runat="server" ID="CVLlantaRodando" OnServerValidate="CVLlantaRodando_ServerValidate" 
                        Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="Edicion" ForeColor="Red" />
                    <%--2024-02-20: Validacion que indica si la llanta realmente estaba en esa ubición--%>
                    <asp:CustomValidator ErrorMessage="No instalada" ControlToValidate="TBIdLlanta"
                        runat="server" ID="CVUbicacionLlanta" OnServerValidate="CVUbicacionLlanta_ServerValidate" 
                        Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="Edicion" ForeColor="Red" />
                    <%--2024-02-27: Validacion que indica si la llanta ya fue registrada en el ViewState--%>
                    <asp:CustomValidator ErrorMessage="Repetida" ControlToValidate="TBIdLlanta"
                        runat="server" ID="CVRepetidaViewState" OnServerValidate="CVRepetidaViewState_ServerValidate" 
                        Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="Edicion" ForeColor="Red" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="DDLUbicacionLlanta" DataTextField="NumeroInt" DataValueField="NumeroInt" AutoPostBack="true">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    <%--2024-02-20: Validacion que busca que obligatoriamente se ingresen datos--%>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ErrorMessage="Requerido" ControlToValidate="DDLUbicacionLlanta" runat="server"
                        Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="Edicion" ForeColor="Red" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="DDLProfundidadLlanta" DataTextField="NumeroDecimal" DataValueField="NumeroDecimal" AutoPostBack="true">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    <%--2024-02-20: Validacion que busca que obligatoriamente se ingresen datos--%>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ErrorMessage="Requerido" ControlToValidate="DDLProfundidadLlanta" runat="server"
                        Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="Edicion" ForeColor="Red" />
                    <%--2024-02-20: Validacion que indica si la profundidad es menor a la medida anterior--%>
                    <asp:CustomValidator ErrorMessage="Profundidad Mayor" ControlToValidate="DDLProfundidadLlanta"
                        runat="server" ID="CVProfundidadLlanta" OnServerValidate="CVProfundidadLlanta_ServerValidate" 
                        Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="Edicion" ForeColor="Red" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="DDLOperacionLlanta" DataTextField="TextoString" DataValueField="TextoString" AutoPostBack="true">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    <%--2024-02-21: Validacion que busca que obligatoriamente se ingresen datos--%>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ErrorMessage="Requerido" ControlToValidate="DDLOperacionLlanta" runat="server"
                        Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="Edicion" ForeColor="Red" /
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="DDLEstadoLlanta" DataTextField="TextoString" DataValueField="TextoString" AutoPostBack="true">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    <%--2024-02-21: Validacion que busca que obligatoriamente se ingresen datos--%>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ErrorMessage="Requerido" ControlToValidate="DDLEstadoLlanta" runat="server"
                        Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="Edicion" ForeColor="Red" /
                </td>
                <td>    
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TBHorometroEquipo" TextMode="Number" />
                    <%--2024-02-20: Validacion que busca que obligatoriamente se ingresen datos--%>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ErrorMessage="Requerido" ControlToValidate="TBHorometroEquipo" runat="server"
                        Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="Edicion" ForeColor="Red" />
                    <%--2024-02-21: Validacion que busca identificar si el horometro es mayor o igual al anterior--%>
                    <asp:CustomValidator ErrorMessage="Horometro menor" ControlToValidate="TBHorometroEquipo" 
                        runat="server" ID="CVHorometroEquipo" OnServerValidate="CVHorometroEquipo_ServerValidate" 
                        Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="Edicion" ForeColor="Red" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TBOdometroEquipo" TextMode="Number" />
                    <%--2024-02-21: Validacion que busca que obligatoriamente se ingresen datos--%>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ErrorMessage="Requerido" ControlToValidate="TBOdometroEquipo" runat="server"
                        Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="Edicion" ForeColor="Red" />
                    <%--2024-02-21: Validacion que busca identificar si el odometro es mayor o igual al anterior--%>
                    <asp:CustomValidator ErrorMessage="Odometro menor" ControlToValidate="TBOdometroEquipo" 
                        runat="server" ID="CVOdometroEquipo" OnServerValidate="CVOdometroEquipo_ServerValidate" 
                        Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="Edicion" ForeColor="Red" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%--Aqui debo poner el ValidationGroup para que todas las validaciones agrupadas, se realicen al dar click--%>
                    <asp:LinkButton Text="Validar" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-sm btn-success" ID="LBValidarAgregar" OnClick="LBValidarAgregar_Click" 
                        ValidationGroup="Edicion" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <%--Esta es la parte donde se van mostrando y almacenando los registros previso a su insersion en 
            la base de datos.--%>
        <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="GVTabla" CssClass="table" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="IdLlanta" DataField="IdLlanta" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="UbicacionLlanta" DataField="UbicacionLlanta" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="ProfundidadLlanta" DataField="ProfundidadLlanta" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="OperacionLlanta" DataField="OperacionLlanta" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="EstadoLlanta" DataField="EstadoLlanta" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="HorometroEquipo" DataField="HorometroEquipo" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="OdometroEquipo" DataField="OdometroEquipo" />
            </Columns>
            <EmptyDataTemplate>
                <div class="alert alert-info">
                    No ha ingresado llantas.
                </div>
            </EmptyDataTemplate>
        </asp:GridView>
        <td>
            <%--2024-02-28: Validacion de las cantidades de llantas registradas en el ViewState cuya 
                operación fue montaje--%>
            <asp:CustomValidator ErrorMessage="Cantidad Montaje" ControlToValidate="GVTabla" 
                runat="server" ID="CVCantidadMontaje" OnServerValidate="CVCantidadMontaje_ServerValidate" 
                Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="Cantidad" ForeColor="Red" />
            <%--2024-02-28: Validacion de las cantidades de llantas registradas en el ViewState cuya 
                operación fue desmontaje--%>
            <asp:CustomValidator ErrorMessage="Cantidad Desmontaje" ControlToValidate="GVTabla" 
                runat="server" ID="CVCantidadDesmontaje" OnServerValidate="CVCantidadDesmontaje_ServerValidate" 
                Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="Cantidad" ForeColor="Red" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <%--2024-02-28: Con esto boton valido las cantidades de llantas y realizo la insersion en la base de datos--%>
            <asp:LinkButton Text="Insertar" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-sm btn-success" ID="LBValidarInsertar" 
                OnClick="LBValidarInsertar_Click" ValidationGroup="Cantidad" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <%--2024-02-28: Con este boton redirecciono al usuario al informe--%>
            <asp:LinkButton Text="Ir al Informe" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-sm btn-success" ID="LBIrInforme" 
                OnClick="LBIrInforme_Click" />
        </td>
 

    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Cuando vamos a la pagina web, y damos clic en el menú relacionado con este código, nos aparece lo siguiente:

[image: Error presentado al dar clic en el menú]

Agradecemos la ayuda que puedan brindarnos para identificar el error.

Answer (score 0):

El error estaba relacionado con cerrar unas etiquetas, estas fueron las etiquetas abiertas:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ErrorMessage="Requerido" ControlToValidate="DDLOperacionLlanta" runat="server"
                    Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="Edicion" ForeColor="Red" /


<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ErrorMessage="Requerido" ControlToValidate="DDLEstadoLlanta" runat="server"
                    Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="Edicion" ForeColor="Red" /
```

Para poder cerrar las etiqueas solo faltaba en cada una poner el simbolo > al final, quedando asi:

```
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ErrorMessage="Requerido" ControlToValidate="DDLOperacionLlanta" runat="server"
                    Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="Edicion" ForeColor="Red" />


<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ErrorMessage="Requerido" ControlToValidate="DDLEstadoLlanta" runat="server"
                    Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="Edicion" ForeColor="Red" />
```

Algo que me ayudo a encontrar con facilidad el error, fue escribir el contenido de las etiquetas de manera vertical, así:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator 
                    ErrorMessage="Requerido" 
                    ControlToValidate="DDLOperacionLlanta" 
                    runat="server"
                    Display="Dynamic" 
                    ValidationGroup="Edicion" ForeColor="Red"
                />

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator 
                    ErrorMessage="Requerido" 
                    ControlToValidate="DDLEstadoLlanta" 
                    runat="server"
                    Display="Dynamic" 
                    ValidationGroup="Edicion" 
                    ForeColor="Red"
                />
```